# WaitForm management in nested calls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a a wait form `FormWait` (long running task notification), that has `ShowMessage(string message)` function.

Often happens in code:

```
public RootCall() 
{
   FormWait.ShowMessage("Begin long task 1..."); 

   ChildCall();

   FormWait.CloseForm();   
}

public ChildCall() 
{
   FormWait.ShowMessage("Begin long task 2..."); 

   // some code here

   FormWait.CloseForm();   
}
```

`FormWait` on root shows the message to the user, but *before* closing it on root level, there is another `ShowMessage`  of child and `CloseForm` of child.

I have a couple of solutions to resolve this:

1. Like in code provided the methods are static and operate on one static `System.Windows.Forms.Form` instance. On every  `ShowMessage` there is a static variable that *increments* and on every `CloseForm` it *decrements*. So by looking on that variable I can understand if I *really* need to close the form (if I'm or not on root level), or its just a nested `CloseForm` call. And on every `ShowMessage` new string just updated on already visible form.
2. For every new `ShowMessage` call create new instance of the form, but this is really wired to see. So almost sure I will not pick this solution.

Any ideas, how can I manage WaitForm (form that signals to user about long running tasks) in case of nested calls, by making also the developer life easier.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack<> class is the natural fit for this:

```
public partial class WaitForm : Form {
    private WaitForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private static WaitForm instance;
    private static Stack<string> messages = new Stack<string>();

    public static void ShowMessage(string message) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new WaitForm();
            instance.FormClosed += delegate { instance = null; };
            instance.Show();
        }
        messages.Push(message);
        instance.lblMessage.Text = message;
        instance.Update();
    }

    public static void CloseForm() {
        messages.Pop();
        if (instance != null) {
            if (messages.Count == 0) instance.Close();
            else instance.lblMessage.Text = messages.Peek();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put the CloseForm() call in a finally block so this is all exception safe.

Comment: Similiar to "static counter" stuff, but nicer.May be I would not call Peek() last message (if any) on close, cause there is no IMHO really sence, from UI point of view,  bring back to UI the message appeared before.

Comment: Well, pick your message text better.  Instead of "Begin foo" write "Working on foo".  That way the visible text accurately represents the state of the program.